# Changing language of Geany from Arabic to English

Tags: geany

How can I change the language of the IDE "Geany" to English, And how change the theme to black
And thanks.

Comment: Please see the official documentation https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html

Comment: @JohnDizzle, There is no reference to changing language at the link that you posted.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is given by the [Geany FAQ](https://www.geany.org/documentation/faq/#QQuestions11) and I quote,

> How can I change the language of the user interface? On Windows
>
> The easiest way to use English instead of your system's locale is to
> deselect the "Language Files" (a.k.a translations) option when running
> the Windows installer. Then no translation files are installed and
> Geany will use English as language.

And,

> On non-Windows systems
>
> Simply start Geany like this:
>
> LANG=C geany

And in case you cannot reinstall geany for some reason,on windows you can do something like this:

```
cmd.exe /c "set ^"LANG=en^" & start /D ^"C:\installed-path\Geany\bin\^" geany.exe"
```

Check our that link for further possibilities.

p.s. it helps sometimes to generalize a question, like "How to change the language of Geany", I think.

Answer (score 3):

In the 'c:\Program Files\Geany\share\locale' folder you can delete all folders with localization files (or move them to another location, just in case), leaving only the English localization - folders 'en', 'en @ boldquot' , 'en @ quot', 'en @ shaw'
The next time you start Geany, it will start up with an English interface.

To change the theme to black, you need to select the 'View' menu item and select 'Change Color Scheme'. In the window that appears, you can choose a theme to your liking - the interface changes interactively.

Comment: I deleted all Geany's language bloatwares, it works. Thanks 